# How to find the amount of positive numbers

Tags: r

I am new in the world of `R`, and have a rather easy questions, however it troubles me.

I have a load of numbers:

```
abc=rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1)
```

I want to find out how many of these numbers which are positive. I tried:

```
length(which(abc>0)
```

but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean that dint work? Did it give you an error message? `length(which(abc>0))` should work perfectly! Another way is: `sum(abc > 0)`

Comment: I think you don't have a `)` at the end! Read the error messages.

Comment: Well, it seems to be working now.

Comment: Use RStudio (IDE for R), it takes care of proper bracketing and many other things!

Answer (score 5):

What you want is:

```
sum(abc > 0)
```

try `abc > 0` first. This will give you a Boolean vector TRUE for all `abc` values that are positive, length of both `abc` and the Boolean vector identical. Since TRUE is equal to 1 and FALSE is equal to 0, the sum of the elements of that vector will give you the desired count. This is a common trick in R, which is why I felt it could be the answer in your case.

Another useful trick is doing the same but with `mean`, e.g. `mean(abc > 0)` This will give you a *proportion* of values in `abc` which are positive.

Your original approach would also work (provided correct bracketing), but to my taste which() is not the function intended for such use.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `table` here , to give you amount of positive and negative numbers :

```
table(abc > 0 )
FALSE  TRUE 
   45    55
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you should try:

```
length(abc[abc>0])
```

In R everything enters in form of matrices, that is why we use `[]` instead of `()`.